# Retrieve POST response data with cURL

Tags: bash, curl, http-post

In jQuery/AJAX you can make POST requests and get their response with something like

```
$.post(url, data, function(res){ 
  //do something
});
```

Where res contains the server's response. I am trying to replicate this with cURL in bash.

```
curl -d "data=data" --cookie cookies.txt --header "Content-Type:text/html" https://example.com/path > result.html
```

Returns gibberish (some sort of js object maybe?), but I am expecting html. Is there a way to retrieve the data that would be in res using cURL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the order of the url and header. They were in the correct order in the script I'm using (I've done get requests successfully). I edited the question to fix this.

Comment: How garbled is the gibberish? If it is a real mess that might be compressed data, try passing `--compressed` to curl.

Comment: The result after passing `--compressed`, with a few characters swapped is: ‹íýGŽ$IÒ¼ÿïˆ;(<¹sM²KhØ&r‘«ŒÑL3ÀÌÔÓK==ýö‰´@"k.‘ =AI-ÙPdiÒÌæþæ^ä“œ¹,ÒlKy'¼˜„#z<“°ƒ{÷’¥¦«§¡éÇYÌ9¦AüZ¸*ì²Bã•»r€h;”×?üX¸\ªÏzÝ¡ÊV,ÄÆo§)ª.ýqÛ¶Ù'ç¥æTy¬³—‚’~U\;7|Lmi·#0™ÿ´ ­ù=„ÝŽ—ßåìÃO;

Comment: Strange. What's the content-type? Try `curl -si --compressed …`

Comment: Ah, `curl -si --compressed` worked. Actually, just `--compressed` works, I didn't realize it had to go first. Thanks! If you want to make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes servers send back compressed content. It looks like random garbage. Use `curl --compressed` to get the decompressed result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to get a data from a POST request. Server returns you a javascript object. And you are getting it right way, javascript converts returned data to HTML, not cURL. So basically you can't do that.